# How to setup two for £20 on a single product

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, tierprice

How would I go about setting it up so that a product that is normally £15 can be purchased at two for £20?

I.e they get two tickets for £10.00 each if they buy two

Hope that makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use the tier price option in magento. Check this links for a detail description

http://www.hostknox.com/clients/knowledgebase/376/How-to-set-up-quantity-discounts-in-Magento.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUQM07h_17c - Minute 1:42 for tier price part

Comment: I have tried that however the issue is that the sale is not limited to 2 tickets and any number of products can be purchased at the reduced price